# I can't run python game on ubuntu

Tags: python

This is a simple game coded in python 
[the source code](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11645528/)

and when run it in ubuntu 14.04

I've got this error

```
File "pong.py", line 18
self.canvas = canvas
   ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

how can I solve it 
thanks

Comment: do you know what a IndentationError means?

Comment: The file you are using is not indented at all. Python code is very sensitive to indentation. The code you have will not work until it is formatted and indented correctly. http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html

Comment: this has nothing to do with linux or ubuntu

Comment: so there is no solve !! ??

Comment: how did you download this?

Comment: its a simple game from udemy.com

Comment: The code you have posted is not properly formatted and cannot run. You'll have to fix it if you want to run it.

Answer (score -1):

The only delimiter of code bloc in python is a colon (":") and the indentation of the code itself, you have to learn basics of python